# Is there a difference between [compass-css] and [compass-sass] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Well, I noticed these two co-existing tags, [compass-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compass-css) and [compass-sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compass-sass). I guess [compass-sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compass-sass) would be more relevant, since compass works mostly with sass.

However, in a recent question, I was quite hesitating between the two tags.

Is there a reason for this co-existence? Shouldn't they be merged?

Comment: @Bart, thanks for editing. You made me discover this "tag-style" feature :)

Comment: The `compass` tag was burninated because it was being used for both the SASS/CSS framework and for, well, compasses, which now live in [tag:compass-geolocation].  We don't want to recreate it.  [See previous](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147784/135887).

Comment: That makes sense for the [compass] tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just noticed these two tags being used together on a single question.

I agree: since Compass uses Sass, not CSS, it makes more sense to call the tag [compass-sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compass-sass).

Merged.

Comment: Any reason, to not just have `compass` combined with the specific tags `css` and `sass`?